# Lambert W function multiplied by a constant

Tags: special-functions

Consider the equation

$$y=x e^x.$$
Its real solution is given by
$$x=W(y),$$
where $W$ is the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) (or product log).

Can the function

$$f(x) = W\left(-\frac{1}{r}xe^x\right)$$

be written in simple terms of $x$?

What I've tries so for is writing this as a power series expansion

$$W(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n n^{n-2}}{(n-1)!}x^n$$

therefore with the constant I've introduced
$$
\begin{split}
W\left(-\frac{1}{r}x\right) & =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n-1} n^{n-2}}{(n-1)!}\left(-\frac{x}{r}\right)^n\\
& =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}-\frac{(-1)^{n-1}(-1)^{n-1} n^{n-2}}{(n-1)!}\left(\frac{x}{r}\right)^n \\
& =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}-\frac{n^{n-2}}{(n-1)!}\left(\frac{x}{r}\right)^n
\end{split}
$$
but got stuck here.

I've also tried guessing many functions in mathematica that yeilded no result.

As I see it now the problem is not solvable

Comment: One thing to be aware of is that the domain of the Lambert function isn't closed under $y \mapsto -\frac1 r y$, so you'll have to be careful about where your $f$ is defined.

Comment: @LSpice, $x$ is positive and real, and  $r>0$, does that help?

Comment: Probably not much; still the function is defined only on $(0, W(r/e))$.

Comment: @LSpice, Consider just the zero'th branch.

Comment: What have you tried?  Did you graph the function?  Did you calculate a few terms of its Taylor series?  If so, what did you see?

Comment: @DanielMcLaury, see edit. did you downvote the post?

Comment: I did not downvote the post.

Comment: I honestly think it is a legitimate question, I don't understand why it was downvoted.

Comment: @PietroMajer, a typo, apologies.

Answer (score 2):

If what you want is a series expansion in powers of $x$ and $t:=1/r$, we can write
$$f(x,t)=W\big(- {txe^x}\big)=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty  {q_n(t)} \,x^n=-\bigg[tx+\frac{2t+2t^2}{2!}\, {x^2} +\frac{3t+12t^2+9t^3}{3!}\,x^3+\dots\bigg]$$
The coefficient $q_n$ is a  polynomial  of degree $n$, precisely
$$q_n(t)=\frac{1}{n!}(tD)^{n-1}(1+t)^n$$
where $D$ denotes differentiation in $t$.

Comment: I did not understand what you have done, $r$ is a parameter. I'm also interested in a closed form, or the closest thing I can get to it. Getting to  a closed form through a power series is one option out of many I was hoping people would lay out here.

Comment: I just wrote the power series expansion of $f(x)=W(-x e^x/r)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty q_nx^n$. Of course he coefficients $q_n$ depend on the parameter $r$; in fact they are polynomials in $t:=1/r$.

Comment: @jarhead -- the closed form exists, it is $y = W(-r^{-1}xe^x)$, resumming the power series, either this one or the one in my answer, will just give you back that closed-form expression.

Comment: Indeed it seems difficult to have a better closed form. Instead, I would look at the dependence from $r$; for instance, if I'm not wrong, $f_s\circ f_r=f_r\circ f_s=W\circ f_{-sr}$

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what is $D$, I apologize as it seems basic, but if I take a derivative of $r$ with respect to $x$ then I will get $0$ as it is a parameter.

Comment: Also, If you think this is an exact answer, can you show on a graph for some choice of $r$ to which order $n$ of this polynomial you get a good approximation?

Comment: $D=d/dt$, the derivative w.r.to $t$, and $tD$ is derivative followed by multiplication by $t$, so e.g. $(tD)(1+t)^2=2t +2t^2  $ and $(tD)^2(1+t)^3=3t+12t^2+9t^3$

Answer (score 1):

Maple did the following.  (Of course once you see it you can do it yourself...)

$$
y = W(-\frac{1}{r}xe^x)
$$
solve for $x$; result
$$
x = W(-rye^y)
$$

---

Probably even your original assertion needs adjustment.  We may think that
$$
W(xe^x) = x
$$
but perhaps not.  Here is the graph for $W_0(xe^x)$
[image: W0graph]

Only part of that is $y=x$.

For more explanation, see this, where $W_0(xe^x)$ is in red and $W_{-1}(xe^x)$ is in blue:

[image: two Ws]

Comment: thanks for your effort but this not address the question.

Comment: also I'm only worried about $x>0$ so the $-1$ real branch is not an issue. Still no solution.

Comment: I expect the best solution is $x = W(-rye^y)$ which has no simpler form for general $r$.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Gerald Edgar, you seek to simplify 
$$y = W(-r^{-1}xe^x)\Rightarrow x=W(-rye^y),$$
for $r>0$. Here is a series expansion in powers of $r$,

$$x=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{n-1}\frac{1}{n!}(rye^y)^n.$$

The plot compares the exact result for $x$ (blue curve) with the series expansion up to $n=8$ (gold) at $y=-1$, as a function of $r$. (I take $y<0$ because the OP says the interest is in $x>0$.) The series expansion remains quite accurate even for $r$ approaching unity.

[image]

Comment: and can you transform this series to obtain a continuous function of $f(x)$ when $y=f(x)$?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean; the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{n-1}\frac{1}{n!}(rye^y)^n$ is a contiuous function of $y$; if you are asking whether the series can be summed in closed form, the answer is "yes", but that would bring you back to the Lambert W-function, which you wish to avoid.

Comment: please refer again to my question